# appendChild on load

Tags: javascript, onload, appendchild

So the question is, why doesn't this append the div's on load? I'm scratching my head on this one. No errors... Just not loading.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var divTag0 = document.createElement("div");
            divTag0.className = "newsBlock";
            divTag0.innerHTML = " Try this..";
            document.getElementById("newsLeft").appendChild(divTag0);

            var divTag1 = document.createElement("div");
            divTag1.className = "newsBlock";
            divTag1.innerHTML = " Blah..";
            document.getElementById("newsRight").appendChild(divTag1);

            var divTag2 = document.createElement("div");
            divTag2.className = "newsBlock";
            divTag2.innerHTML = " And this ..";
            document.getElementById("newsLeft").appendChild(divTag2);    
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <p> Something filler </p>
    <div id="newsLeft">  
    </div>
    <div id="newsRight">     
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload="load()";
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If azhrei's answer doesn't work, the only thing I could think of would be that calling onload after it has loaded might not trigger, you can change this from your example by simply calling load();

I tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvillars/BZsvh/)

Hope this helps

EDIT:

I believe azhrei has the right of it, it's not so much that the onload isn't triggering, it's that there's a syntax problem with your onload call.

But this code can also be improved in terms of better style (more readable/ easier to comprehend) by removing the second JS call.

In the header if you write:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    //everything inside your load() function goes here
}
```

It works just as well. It also removes a lot of the fluff that was just kind of there. I hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't aware of just calling the funtion. Semi newb to javascript.

Comment: This helped me find the other bug here... So, you don't need to explicitly reload... Just set your window.onload function to a function, not a string. :-) I've updated my answer with this.

Comment: I just made an edit that I think harkens to what azhrei was saying and also provides better overall style than my solution yesterday. I hope that helps even more.

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to supply a string to [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) ...

So that:
`document.getElementById(newsLeft).appendChild(divTag0);`

Should be:
`document.getElementById("newsLeft").appendChild(divTag0);`

But the main problem is:
`window.onload="load()";`

Which should be:
`window.onload=load;`

Thanks to jvillars for the fiddle, which helped me notice this.

Comment: Yeah tried it prior with no success. So even with the quotes it doesn't work.